# Installing PHP 8.0 on ubuntu 22.10

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I recently updated my server on Ubuntu 22.10 but then installing php8.0 was impossible
What I did:

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

LOG

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports kinetic-security InRelease
Ign:5 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
Ign:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:7 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release'     does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/sarge/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

My application needs php8.0 to work and so the only way for me to make it work is to have php 8.0 installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-php-8-1-and-set-up-a-local-development-environment-on-ubuntu-22-04) explains how to install PHP 8.1. Maybe just changing the version number it works.

Comment: no it will not work I tried
E: Unable to locate package php8.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0'

Comment: Sorry if I'm telling you things you have already tried but searching I found someone who could fix it: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/yt5rxn/comment/j06aa17/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x

Comment: dont be sorry at all i want very much to fix this i have tried lots of things i am looking for 2 days now

Comment: solved it with what this guy said in the comment:

I solved it by changing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list. deb

https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main
# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/kinetic main
Of course, run the apt update command

Answer (score 1):

If we type in the following command into an Ubuntu 22.10 terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

We will see the following error:

E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.

At the time of writing this article, the ondrej repository DOES NOT support Ubuntu 22.10 (code name kinetic). Hence the reference in the message to Ubuntu kinetic Release.

The solution is very simple, first, we edit the ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-kinetic.list
```

And replace the word kinetic in the first line to read:

```
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ jammy main
```

Save the changes and update the system.

```
sudo apt update
```

reference

https://www.davidl.co.uk/post/installing-php-7x-on-ubuntu-2210-kinetic