# Installing php8.0-gd extension has unmet dependencies libavif13 (>= 0.9.3)

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to install php8.0-gd but I get this log

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libavif13 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

command: php -v

```
PHP 8.0.28 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:33:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.28, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

command: lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:        22.10
Codename:       kinetic
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 comes with PHP 8.1. Where did you install PHP 8.0 from?

Comment: hello Alex, here is how i installed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758912/installing-php-8-0-on-ubuntu-22-10/75759386

Comment: The ondrej PPA doesn't have support for 22.10, which is why `add-apt-repository` errored out when you first tried running it. By following the comments on that post, you've installed 22.04 binaries to a 22.10 machine, which you can't really expect to work cleanly. I'd recommend uninstalling 8.0, removing the Ondrej PPA, and then installing 8.1 from the native repository.

Comment: I can't do that because my application is not ready for 8.1 thats why all this.

Comment: It's not a big lift to go from 8.0 to 8.1. You can use [Rector](https://getrector.com/) to help discover and apply any needed patches. If you absolutely need to stay on 8.0, then I'd recommend dropping back to Ubuntu 22.04 -- then you can use the Ondrej PPA which will give you access to 7.4, 8.0, 8.1, and 8.2. If you absolutely need Ubuntu 22.10 and PHP 8.0, then you'll probably have to compile it from source.

Comment: is that possible? to drop back to 22.04?

Comment: By "dropping back," I don't mean downgrading that machine, I mean using a different machine. Ideally that would mean simply launching a different container or spinning up a parallel VM.

Comment: aw that is not possible specially now, the ideal version of the solution i am looking for is to only install somehow that extension only because one thing leads to another and i would like to avoid that

Comment: Unfortunately, you already went down the "one thing leads to another" road when you installed the 22.04 binaries. I.e., you've now got a machine that will likely fail unpredictably in production later.